# Help me identify an urban fantasy web comic whose main character was named "Resonator"

Tags: story-identification, webcomics, urban-fantasy

I used to read a web comic and I've forgotten it's name and URL.  It was "urban fantasy" where some fantastic things happened in a world that looked like the real world in the present time.  The main character was a young man who used to be an assassin, and his assassin alias was "Resonator".  If I recall correctly he went by "Star" informally (name? nickname? not sure).

The comic featured a group of people who were basically a spy agency, whose missions were literally given to them by angels.  The other main character had the (rare) ability to see and converse with angels.

Star was bisexual and was mostly shown with boyfriends.  One of his boyfriends sold his soul to the Devil; his soul was consigned to Hell and his body still walked and talked and could think, but was souless.  Star managed somehow to win back the soul, and the boyfriend was emotionally devastated by his memories of several days in Hell.  I remember Star yelling at someone (an angel?  a representative of angels?) for allowing such things to happen, which I thought was unfair.

Star was extremely interested in the other main character, who possibly reciprocated, but the other main character was trying to avoid any romance in his life as he needed to stay a virgin to continue to be able to talk to angels.

Star started working for the agency, and right away there was a mission where they needed to rescue someone from some really bad guys.  Star told the mission commander something to the effect of "You guys are a team and have trained together.  I've always worked alone.  I'm not giving you attitude, I'm stating facts.  This will work better if you give me a solo job, and the rest of you do your team thing."  The commander said something like "Fine, you're the point man."  So Star went in, alone, ahead of the others, and cleverly figured out and disabled some nasty traps.

In another memorable scene, a group of Mafia guys are in a meeting, and the head guy complains that assassins who know too much don't get to just retire.  He says something like "I will consider the man who kills Resonator to be a personal friend."

I read this years ago.  As far as I know it stopped updating at least five years ago, maybe more.  As I remember it, it was hand-drawn and black-and-white.

What was this comic?  Google is not very helpful; there are a surprising number of web comics featuring angels, and the words "Star" and "Resonator" don't seem to help.

Comment: Does this help a bit? [Deal With The Devil / Web Comics](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/DealWithTheDevil/Webcomics). Warning: tv tropes.

Comment: The comic definitely wasn't _Homestuck_ or _Sluggy Freelance_ or any of the other comics on that TV Tropes page.  Sorry, didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought of a new way to research this: people like to make lists of things, so maybe the fact that the protagonist is bisexual would mean that I could find this comic in a list.  Lo and behold, this list page:

http://theslashpile.tumblr.com/lgbtqwebcomics

has a section with inactive comics, and when I spotted the name of the comic in the list it jogged my memory.  The comic was called: Metanoia

Here's its web page.  Unfortunately it seems pretty broken right now.  I can see that Chapter One is called "Resonator" but I can't read the comic.

http://metanoia.studiowhippingboy.com/index.shtml

Here's the TVTropes page for it:

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/Metanoia

The other protagonist was Zander, and I forgot that he is "Ridden" by an angel and to keep his "Ridden" status is why he must stay a virgin.  So I think Star was talking to an angel in the scene I remembered, where he was complaining that it shouldn't be possible for people to sell their soul to the Devil.